# Differentiate Archimedes's spiral

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I read that the only problem of differential calculus Archimedes solved was constructing the tangent to his spiral,
$$r = a + b\theta$$
I would like to differentiate it but I don't know much about differentiating polar functions and can't find this particular problem online. Without giving me a full course in differential geometry, how does one calculate the tangent to the curve at $\theta$?

Comment: Since $r$ is a function of $\theta$ you can differentiate it wrt. $\theta$ to get $b$. If you are interested in tangent lines, you might want to convert it to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @SbareS Don't you mean $m$? I want to be able to construct the tangent to a point. All you need is the slope because you can calculate $x$ and $y$ using $r$ and $\theta$ and then you can use the point-slope formula to get the equation for your line.

Comment: Right, but to do that you will need Cartesian coordinates. I am posting an answer with an example of how to do it.

Comment: @SbareS Thanks.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "tangent to the curve at $\theta$". In polar coordinates the "tangent to the curve at $\theta$" is given by $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=b$. In cartesian coordiantes the "tangent to the curve" is given by $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\theta}\times\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ which can be expressed in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I will edit it further and then restore it.

Comment: ${}^\wedge$ and now I've restored it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r(\theta)=a+b\theta$ the equation of the Archimedean spiral.

The cartesian coordinates of a point with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ are 
$$\left\{\begin{align}
x(r,\theta)&=r\cos\theta\\
y(r,\theta)&=r\sin\theta
\end{align}\right.
$$
so a point on the spiral has coordinates
$$\left\{\begin{align}
x(\theta)&=r(\theta)\cos\theta=(a+b\theta)\cos\theta\\
y(\theta)&=r(\theta)\sin\theta=(a+b\theta)\sin\theta
\end{align}\right.
$$
Differentiating we have
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
x'(\theta)&=b\cos\theta-(a+b\theta)\sin\theta\\
y'(\theta)&=b\sin\theta+(a+b\theta)\cos\theta
\end{align}\right.
$$
The parametric equation of a line tangent to the spiral at the point $(r(\theta_0),\theta_0)$ is
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
x(\theta)&=x(\theta_0)+x'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)=x(\theta_0)+[b\cos\theta_0-(a+b\theta_0)\sin\theta_0](\theta-\theta_0)\\
y(\theta)&=y(\theta_0)+y'(\theta_0)(\theta-\theta_0)=x(\theta_0)+[b\sin\theta_0+(a+b\theta_0)\cos\theta_0](\theta-\theta_0)
\end{align}\right.
$$
or in cartesian form
$$
y(\theta)-y(\theta_0)=\frac{y'(\theta_0)}{x'(\theta_0)}[x(\theta)-x(\theta_0)]=\frac{b\sin\theta_0+(a+b\theta_0)\cos\theta_0}{b\cos\theta_0-(a+b\theta_0)\sin\theta_0}[x(\theta)-x(\theta_0)]
$$
where the slope of the line is
$$
\frac{y'(\theta)}{x'(\theta)}=\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x}=\frac{b\sin\theta+(a+b\theta)\cos\theta}{b\cos\theta-(a+b\theta)\sin\theta}=\frac{b\tan\theta+(a+b\theta)}{b-(a+b\theta)\tan\theta}
$$

Answer (score 2):

A typical point on the curve is $(x,y)=((a+b\theta)\cos\theta,(a+b\theta)\sin\theta)$.

By the product rule, we have
\begin{align}
dx & = (b\cos\theta-(a+b\theta)\sin\theta)\,d\theta, \\
dy & = (b\sin\theta+(a+b\theta)\cos\theta)\,d\theta.
\end{align}
So the slope at $(x,y)$ is
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b\sin\theta+(a+b\theta)\cos\theta}{b\cos\theta-(a+b\theta)\sin\theta}.
$$

In case $a=0$, this becomes
$$
\frac{\frac y\theta + x}{\frac x \theta - y} = \frac{y+\theta x}{x-\theta y}. \tag{$*$}
$$
I don't actually know whether this last form is useful in drawing the graph.

One can also write $(*)$ as
$$
\frac{\frac y x + \theta}{1 - \theta\frac y x} = \frac{\tan\theta+\theta}{1-\theta\tan\theta} = \frac{\tan\tan\eta+\tan\eta}{1-\tan\eta\tan\tan\eta} = \tan(\eta+\tan\eta)
$$
where $\theta=\tan\eta$.

Comment: Why don't any $a$s or $b$s show up in the last form? The slope at (x,y) should depend on a and b.

Comment: @RenéG : You'll notice I said "In case $a=0$".  That's why no $a$ appears.  As for $b$, notice that it cancels from the numerator and the denominator.  For a particular point $(x,y)$ there is only one value of $b$ for which the particular value of $\theta$ would be a point passing through $(x,y)$.  Next we have the question of whether something similar is true of a particular value of the ratio $y/x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier to swallow in complex variables. Let

$$z=(a+b\theta)e^{i\theta}$$
then
$$\dot z=[(a+b\theta)i+b]e^{i\theta}=[(a+b\theta)i+b][\text{cos}\theta + i\text{sin}\theta]$$

from which the previous results for $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ can be readily obtained. However, we don't need that to get the tangent, because it is, in fact, just $\dot z$, with the caveat that you need to express it as an angle, let's call it $\Theta$. Thus,

$$\Theta=\text{tan}^{-1}\frac{\mathfrak{Im}(\dot z)}{\mathfrak{Re}(\dot z)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize it in the cartesian plane as
$$s(t)=\begin{pmatrix}bt\cos(t-a/b)\\bt\sin(t-a/b)\end{pmatrix}$$
So the direction of the tangent line at a point $s(t)$ is given by
$$s'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}b\cos(t-a/b)-bt\sin(t-a/b)\\b\sin(t-a/b)+bt\cos(t-a/b)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Sorry...what's $b$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are from your question!

Comment: Oh that $b$!!! Nevermind...

Comment: Can you explain a little more how your paramaterization works?

Comment: In your parametrization, $\theta$ goes from $-a/b$ to $\infty$ (to make $r$ go from $0$ to $\infty$). In my parametrization, I use $t$ going from $0$ to $\infty$ instead, so $\theta=t-a/b$, $r=a+\theta=a+b(t-a/b)=bt$ and the cartesian coordinates are $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)=(bt\cos(t-b/a), bt\sin(t-b/a))$. But you could use $\theta$ if you want, then it would be $s(\theta)=((a+b\theta, cos\theta, (a+b\theta, \sin\theta)$.

Comment: How did you calculate $s'(t)$?

Comment: Product rule, $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, so e.g. $(bt)(\cos(t-a/b))'=(bt)'\cos(t-a/b)+bt(\cos(t-a/b))'=b\cos(t-a/b)+bt(-\sin(t-a/b))$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19678/discussion-between-rene-g-and-user2345215).